# how to call javascript function repetitively in console

Tags: javascript, html, timer

```
var ele=Boolean(document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML>=30)
while(ele==false)
if(ele){
```

I want to constantly check this and run it once it is true. How can I do this? I want to only run the while loop to then run the if loop but, in console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use setInterval to build a function to execute something, and when your condition is true use clearInterval(id) to stop it.

type this on your console :
refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){console.log('hi'); if((new Date).getMinutes() > 27){clearInterval(refreshIntervalId)} }, 1000);

Answer (score 2):

A test of running a `while` loop in the console swiftly crashed my browser.  Not a good idea.  Try using a `setInterval` in the page instead.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="seconds">30</div>
<script>
var myTest;
myTest = setInterval(checkElement, 100);
// elem is set outside the function so the function runs quicker, but in reality, this won't make a significant difference in this example
var elem = document.getElementById("seconds");
function checkElement(){
     if(parseInt(elem.textContent)>30){
          console.log(Math.random());
          clearInterval(myTest);
     }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```